# Custom Figure numbering for Part, chapter, figure

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, numbering

I'm using a book document class to write my thesis. I have three distinct themes running throughout my thesis and so I have it divided by 4 parts. Within each part, there are three chapters and I would like to number the figures so that the Part number precedes the chapter number.

currently I have it as just the Figure1(chapter).x(figure number).
Figure 1.1 Figure 2.1 etc...

For example a figure in part 1 would be: Figure 1(part).1(chapter).x(figure number)
I want to be able to get Figure 1.1.1, Figure 1.2.1

Comment: It seems to work with the following command in the preamble
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```